# How does -t flag keep a container running?

Tags: docker

When I run a busybox container with '-t' flag, it remains in "Running" state but without the "-t" flag, the container goes to "exit" state.
How does -t flag effect container state?

```
$ docker run -d --name mybzy busybox -> container exits
$ docker run -dt --name mybzy1 busybox -> container keeps running
```

Comment: "Keep a container running" shouldn't usually be a goal on its own; if the container exits it means the main container process exited.  You wouldn't usually run basic images like `busybox` or `ubuntu` on their own, but rather package an application into an image based on them, such that when the container is run, it launches the application.

Answer (score 1):

The default CMD of `busybox` is running a shell. Running a docker container with `-t` means connecting it to the terminal. A shell prompts the user for input if its connected to a shell (and only if).

When running without `-t`, the container is not connected to your terminal, and the shell program just exits.